# Is it possible to set enable to ConstraintLayout in instrumental test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

`Android studio 3.6`

My `xml` layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/waitressCallContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/quarter_default_margin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBarContainer"
    app:layout_goneMarginTop="@dimen/default_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waitressCallViewCircle"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Before click on `waitressCallContainer` I need to set `waitressCallContainer` to `isEnabled  = true` and `isClickable = true`.
In my code (my `Activity`) is smt like this:

```
 dataBinding.waitressCallContainer.isClickable = true
 dataBinding.waitressCallViewCircle.isEnabled = true
```

Nice. 
But I need to do this aslo in my `instrumental test`.

```
@Test
    fun waitressCallContainer_click_successResponse_buttonChangeState() {
        //stub response
        mockServer.enqueue(
            MockResponse()               
                .setResponseCode(200)
        )

        waitressCallContainer.click()
        val request = mockServer.takeRequest();
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.waitressCallContainer))
            .check(matches(withText("Call is made")))
```

So before call

```
waitressCallContainer.click()
```

I need to set:

```
waitressCallContainer.isClickable = true
waitressCallViewCircle.isEnabled = true
```

Is it possible in `instrumental` test (e.g. by `Espresso`, or maybe `UIAutomator`) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way of doing this.

**First option**

With this private function:

```
private fun <T>callMethod(message: String = "", someMethod: (view: T) -> Unit): ViewAction {
    return object: ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return if(message.isBlank()) someMethod.toString() else message
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isEnabled()
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            someMethod(view!! as T)
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to call those methods on those views this way:

```
onView(withId(R.id.waitressCallContainer))
    .perform(callMethod<View>("call isClickable() method") {
    it.isClickable = true
})

onView(withId(R.id.waitressCallViewCircle))
    .perform(callMethod<View>("call isEnabled() method") {
    it.isEnabled = true
})
```

---

**Second option**

The above solution is not the only way of doing it, with a couple of custom `ViewActions` (one for each element) you could also execute each of the instructions you need, all in espresso:

```
private fun setClickable(): ViewAction {
    return object: ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Set clickable"
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isEnabled()
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            view?.isClickable = true
        }
    }
}

private fun setEnabled(): ViewAction {
    return object: ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Set enabled"
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isEnabled()
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            view?.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

And call them:

```
onView(withId(R.id.waitressCallViewCircle))
    .perform(setClickable())

onView(withId(R.id.waitressCallViewCircle))
    .perform(setEnabled())
```

But I prefer the first option, using generics and a single method seems much cleaner.